# ksh script if condition not accepting brackets

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

So I am not used to shell scripting. I have a ksh script that has an if coniditon similar to below.

```
if [[ "asdasd" -eq "asdas()d" ]]; then
```

However when this runs it complains that

```
./closedown[36]: asdas()d: unexpected `('
```

I tried escaping it as such

```
if [[ "asdasd" -eq "asdas\(\)d" ]]; then
```

But then it complains about

```
./closedown[36]: asdas\(\)d: unexpected `\'
```

Hoping someone can help me out here, cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-eq` is for numeral comparison and needs numbers on both sides.

Comment: And use `=` or `==` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above comments about using '=' for text comparison as against '-eq' (which is for numerical comparison), double quotes allows shell to try and interpret what you have passed to the if condition.

Change that to use single-quotes - like so:

```
root@bumblebee> [[ 'asdasd' = 'asdas()d' ]] && echo 'Hello:)' || echo 'World:('
World:(

root@bumblebee>
```